# How to get the ObjectId from MongoDB query, using PHP + Ajax()?

Tags: php, ajax, mongodb

I'd like to use a query to return the whole content of a collection.
But, when I use `PHP` to search trigged by `$.ajax()`, it returns the `ObjectId` as `[object Object]`.
I'm trying to get it as a string. How can I proceed?

Following the `$.ajax()` code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'funcoes/registroeventos.php',
    data: {
        "ref": ref
    },
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    },
    success: function (dados) {
        $.each(dados, function () {
            $.each(this, function (index, value) {
                alert(value);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

And then, the `PHP` code:

```
$ref = $_POST['ref'];
try {
    $consulta = ['ref' => $ref, 'excluido' => 'n'];
    $opcoes = [];
    $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($consulta, $opcoes);
    $linhas = $conexao->executeQuery($bd . "maquinas", $query);

    echo json_encode(iterator_to_array($linhas));
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
}
```

Comment: Can you please show what you are getting in dados?

Comment: Phil, I'm sorry. Let me get this straight.Do you wanna see the results of the alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading my json it was clear.

```
 [
{"_id":
   {"$oid":"5aafac02dc32b7f93a3fda00"},
"ref":"DIP001",
"nome":"Dip Tork",
"status":"setup",
"excluido":"n",
"idsetor":"5aafaba2dc32b7f93a3fd9ff"}
]
```

So, a just did it: `alert(dados._id.$oid);`
Instead `alert(dados._id);`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value using following script.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'funcoes/registroeventos.php',
    data: {
        "ref": ref
    },
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    },
    success: function (dados) {
        $.each(dados, function (k,v) {
                alert(v.your_value);
        });
    }
});
```

You need to loop through the response and then you can retrieve values using `v.data, v.message` etc...

Comment: Smit, I did it trying like this: alert(v._id); But it's still returning [object Object]. It works for other fields. But, _id, it doesn't work.

Comment: It returns this json:
[{"_id":{"$oid":"5aafac02dc32b7f93a3fda00"},
"ref":"DIP001",
"nome":"Dip Tork",
"status":"setup",
"excluido":"n",
"idsetor":"5aafaba2dc32b7f93a3fd9ff"}
]